# How can I download this tricky, non-YouTube flash video?

Tags: video, download, flash

Flash video in question is [here](http://video.samaritanspurse.org/van-texas-tornado-recovery-begins/). I'm using the latest version of Firefox on Windows 7.

As stated, the video is not from or on YouTube. I've poked around Firefox's cache and could not find any .swf or .flv file. Addons like VideoDownloadHelper either don't see it or don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), is capable of handling it without any problems, provided you have either ffmpeg or libav installed as well. Here's an overview from their own site:

> *youtube-dl* is a small command-line program to download videos from YouTube.com and a few more sites. It requires the Python interpreter (2.6, 2.7, or 3.2+), and it is not platform specific. We also provide a Windows executable that includes Python. youtube-dl should work in your Unix box, in Windows or in Mac OS X. It is released to the public domain, which means you can modify it, redistribute it or use it however you like.

The basic usage is `youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]`.

If you have avconv or ffmpeg installed, running the command with no options should be enough, but you may need to include a `--ffmpeg-location PATH` if they are not in your PATH environment variable.

---

Alternatively, if you know how and want to handle the HLS yourself, you can specify `--dump-json` and the output will be an object including some metadata extracted from the page, including the m3u8 URL that youtube-dl would otherwise run through avconv or ffmpeg. Here is the one I got: http://player.ooyala.com/player/ipad/82ZHI1dTqN7Gwd8R9-K0su66Mz8-emeI.m3u8?js=1.

Comment: Please read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance in recommending software.

Comment: You may wish to add that you also need ffmpeg -- http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/  to turn the split hsl format into a single .mp4

Comment: Thanks, fixer1234 and Anaksunaman. I have tried to address your issues.